# Can't Run Transformer Fine Tuning With M1 Mac CPU

Tags: macos, gpu, cpu, huggingface-transformers, fine-tuning

Here's the code I use

```
from transformers import DistilBertForSequenceClassification, Trainer, TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          # output directory
    num_train_epochs=1,              # total number of training epochs
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,  # batch size per device during training
    per_device_eval_batch_size=64,   # batch size for evaluation
    warmup_steps=500,                # number of warmup steps for learning rate scheduler
    weight_decay=0.01,               # strength of weight decay
    logging_dir='./logs',            # directory for storing logs
    logging_steps=10,
    use_mps_device=False
)

model = DistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,                         # the instantiated  Transformers model to be trained
    args=training_args,                  # training arguments, defined above
    train_dataset=train_dataset,         # training dataset
    eval_dataset=val_dataset             # evaluation dataset
)
 
device = torch.device("cpu")
model.to(device)
  
trainer.train()
```

I get this error: message

RuntimeError: Placeholder storage has not been allocated on MPS device!

If I change the argument to use_mps_device=True, it will train with GPU, even though the model.to statement is pointing to CPU?

I could get the training to run with GPU but not with CPU.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: @FelipeValdes Yes, see comments below.  Basically I add the no_cuda parameter to TrainingArguments.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `Trainer` automatically moves the model to the appropriate device if the [`place_model_on_device` attribute](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.17.0/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.Trainer) is `True`.

My suggestion would be to remove any moving code & do it through the `transformers` library. You can specify [`no_cuda` in `TrainingArguments`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.17.0/en/main_classes/trainer#transformers.TrainingArguments.no_cuda) as `False` so that the training objects aren't moved to GPU.

Comment: place_model_on_device attribute does not seem to be supported on the Mac version of transformers.  I've got an error message 

Trainer.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'place_model_on_device'

Comment: The no_cuda parameter works.  Now training runs on CPU.  Interestingly, Mac uses AMD GPU, and it uses a library different from CUDA.  It looks like the no_cuda parameter takes on a generic meaning.

Comment: @Nin yes it does seem that `no_cuda` is currently a generic parameter to use CPU regardless of whether the GPU on the device uses CUDA or not (see the source code [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/2dc5e1a120176594ed2dcb7d2f02a5dd62266232/src/transformers/training_args.py#L1748)). There was also this comment on this matter which might be of interest: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/17971#issuecomment-1212743802

Comment: I'm having the same problem and have reported it here: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/17971#issuecomment-1212743802 If I remove the `use_mps_device` line, then I'm getting an error while constructing the `TrainerArguments`. It never gets to the `Trainer`.

Answer (score 1):

I can verify the OP and the response: Trainer is not working properly on my M2 MPS, but does work (painfully slowly) with the MPS turned off with the `no_cuda=True` option under TrainingArguments.

FWIW, the errors that I am getting with the MPS set to be on seem to have to do with storage allocation on the MPS.

Comment: I had the same problem with the storage allocation error msg on my M1 Mac.  I added use_mps_device=True to TrainingArguments and that solved the problem.  I also took out the no_cuda=True option.

Comment: Well, that's my issue: I have an M2, running on torch 2.0.1, but setting no_cuda=False and use_mps_device=True causes the bus error (or a kernel crash in Jupyter). What versions of torch and transformers are you using?

Comment: torch 2.0.1 (same as yours) and transformers 4.30.2

Comment: Odd, my transformers version is 4.30.2 also. Can't really be an M2 vs M1 difference.

Comment: John, if you are interested, I can send you my notebook to try.  It's a movie review classification notebook I grabbed from the internet.  If my notebook fails on your M2, then it may be an M1 vs. M2 issue.

You can create a dummy gmail account so that no private information will be shared.  Unfortunately stackoverflow does not support DM.

Comment: Thanks for offering, Nin, but I'll pass. I see that the nightly-version of torch now doesn't even accept the use_mps_device option, at least as of yesterday, so any  more fiddling on these lines would be a dated solution.

Turns out that my bigger problem is an inappropriate transformer model.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).